# Caused by IllegalStateException: Read and write parameter types are not the same

Tags: grails

Groovy Version: 1.8.1 JVM: 1.6.0_26

Grails Version: 2.0.0M1

visit controller which extends a abstract controller got error.

```
class AbstractController {
    def grailsApplication
    def scaffold = true
    //def index = {redirect(action: "list", params: params)}
}

class VoterController extends AbstractController{
    //def scaffold = true
    def index = {
        println scaffold
        redirect(action: "list", params: params)
    }
}
```

error log:

```
2011-8-17 11:05:23 com.springsource.loaded.agent.SpringLoadedPreProcessor preProcess
严重: Unexpected problem transforming call sites
java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(StringTokenizer.java:332)
    at com.springsource.loaded.MethodInvokerRewriter.ensureCacheIndexLoaded(MethodInvokerRewriter.java:180)
    at com.springsource.loaded.MethodInvokerRewriter.rewriteUsingCache(MethodInvokerRewriter.java:81)
    at com.springsource.loaded.TypeRegistry.methodCallRewriteUseCacheIfAvailable(TypeRegistry.java:728)
    at com.springsource.loaded.agent.SpringLoadedPreProcessor.preProcess(SpringLoadedPreProcessor.java:222)
    at com.springsource.loaded.agent.ClassPreProcessorAgentAdapter.transform(ClassPreProcessorAgentAdapter.java:93)
    at sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(TransformerManager.java:169)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(InstrumentationImpl.java:365)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)

| Loading Grails 2.0.0.M1
| Configuring classpath
| Configuring classpath.
| Environment set to development
| Environment set to development.
| Environment set to development..
| Environment set to development...
| Environment set to development....
| Environment set to development.....
| Packaging Grails application
| Packaging Grails application.
| Packaging Grails application..
| Packaging Grails application...
| Packaging Grails application....
| Compiling 1 source files
| Compiling 1 source files.
| Compiling 1 source files..
| Compiling 1 source files...
| Compiling 1 source files....
| Compiling 1 source files.....
| Running Grails application
| Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080/Vote
| Error 2011-08-17 11:06:19,609 ["http-bio-8080"-exec-1] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - Exception occurred when processing request: [GET] /Vote/voter
Stacktrace follows:
   Line | Method
->> 886 | runTask in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   908 | run     in     ''
^   662 | run . . in java.lang.Thread

Caused by IllegalStateException: Read and write parameter types are not the same
->> 886 | runTask in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   908 | run     in     ''
^   662 | run . . in java.lang.Thread
| Compiling 2 source files
| Compiling 2 source files.
| Compiling 2 source files..
| Compiling 2 source files...
| Compiling 2 source files....
| Compiling 2 source files.....
| Compiling 2 source files
| Compiling 2 source files.
| Error 2011-08-17 11:16:41,422 ["http-bio-8080"-exec-2] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - Exception occurred when processing request: [GET] /Vote/voter
Stacktrace follows:
   Line | Method
->> 886 | runTask in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   908 | run     in     ''
^   662 | run . . in java.lang.Thread

Caused by IllegalStateException: Read and write parameter types are not the same
->> 886 | runTask in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   908 | run     in     ''
^   662 | run . . in java.lang.Thread
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in 2.0 M1 fixed in 2.0 RC1

Comment: yes.I had submit issue and was fixed. forgot to close this Q.